# Worker service, how to make MQTT event subscription uninterrupted？

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

The MQTT client, as the background service program of the windows system, initializes:

```
 public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger,IMqttDataService mqttDataService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _mqttDataService = mqttDataService;       
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await _mqttDataService.Initialize();
            });
        }
```

In this initialization function, after ReceivedHandler, get the data：

```
 _client.UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler(e =>
                {
                    MqttMessageTransport mmt = new MqttMessageTransport
                    {
                        Topic = e.ApplicationMessage.Topic,
                        Message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload)
                    };              
                });
```

However, after the work service program is started, the data can only be obtained at the beginning. After the initialization is performed, the UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler event cannot be activated again, but in the console program, it is OK。